# How do I pass from parent to child component which is not nested?

Tags: angular, decorator

I have 2 components, `list component` and `details component`. How would I pass an object from the list component to the details component?

I know that I have to use the `@Input()` decorator but the problem is that the `details component` is not nested inside `list component`. It is completely on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a parent component that wraps both and controls communication between them, or perhaps you could use a shared service that centers the data.

```
<parent>
  <list [items]="items" (onSelectItem)="itemSelected()"></list>
  <detail [item]="selectedItem"></list>
</parent>
```

Js

```
class ParentComponent {
  items = [...],
  selectedItem = null;

  itemSelected(item){
    this.selectedItem  = item;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a service. Take a look
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction